# query with array in condition

Tags: mysql, arrays

i have the folowing array

$idtimova is id from table lige

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 15 [3] => 20 [4] => 21 
        [5] => 27 [6] => 33 [7] => 40 )
```

I want to make a query on database:

```
$sqllige="SELECT lige 
          from lige where lige.idlige IN(".implode(',',$idtimova).")";  

$con=new Connection(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$res=mysqli_query($con->connect,$sqllige)or die(mysqli_error($con->connect));   

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $lige[]=$row['lige'];

}
```

the problem is that I get a array $lige(column lige from lige table) with only two elements

```
Array ( [0] => Engleska [1] => Spanija ).
```

I want that for each element of the array $idtimova  have a corresponding value in $lige.

Comment: Be **extremely** careful to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) all the data you're injecting into your queries. What you're doing here could be severely damaging if you're allowing arbitrary user data in.

Comment: What are the other value you expect? Also "Engleska" and "Spanija"?

Comment: should be Array ( [0] => Engleska [1] => Engleska [2] => Engleska [3] => Engleska [4] => Spanija [5] => Spanija [6] => Spanija  [7] => Spanija

Comment: the problem is not showing the result of a arrays of elements that are repeated